# Conformal mapping from triangle to unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Since Complex analysis is not my expertise, i want to know if there is a conformal mapping from the triangle (see the figure) to the unit disk. 
[triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLG4S.png)

Thank you very much.

Comment: See also Schwarz Christofell mappings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this follows directly from the [Riemann Mapping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem). However, finding an explicit formula for the map may be difficult. See chapter 8.4 of Stein and Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.